# upstart ubuntu apt-get install fails to configure

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

After installing upstart with

```
sudo apt-get install upstart
```

the command

```
start jobname
```

prints this:

start: Name "com.ubuntu.Upstart" does not exist

what am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

All Upstart commands e.g. initctl, status, start, stop should to be executed as the `root` user or as `sudo`. Running your command with `sudo` or as `root` user should solve your problem.